# How to read windows specific extensions

Tags: c++, opengl

In OpenGL superbible the example says I can read Windows specific extensions via:

```
//Type defined in the book as char, but that is not what glGetString returns...
const GLubyte *extensions = glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS);
if(strstr(extensions, "WGL_EXT_swap_control") != NULL)
{
    wglSwapIntervalEXT = (PFNWGLSWAPINTERVALEXTPROC)wglGetProcAddress("wglSwapIntervalEXT");
    if(wglSwapIntervalEXT != NULL)
        wglSwapIntervalEXT(1);
}
```

`strstr` does not take `GLubyte`.  How can make this work?

Comment: Just cast the return value of `glGetString` to a `const char*`.

Comment: I tried that and got "Unhandled exception at 0x77e315de in block.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000."

Comment: Because `glGetString` returned a NULL-pointer. My guess is you're calling it before having initialized OpenGL or from a different thread (less likely).

Comment: @user786653 - You are correct.  That fixed the problem.  You should post as answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just cast the return value of `glGetString` to a const char pointer and use your favorite string handling functions.

But really I'd recommend using a library, e.g. [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/), for managing extensions.

Comment: I'm still learning the basics right now.  Eventually I will use a library as you suggest.

Comment: Using GLEW will make your life easier, and you won't need to learn things that are of little use in 99% of all cases. And, you won't learn them wrong (the correct answer in respect to WGL is the one by song).

Answer (score 4):

`glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` will return most extensions (*separated by spaces*) that are supported by the video card. But windows specific **WGL_** extensions (for OpenGL version 3.0+) are NOT included with this call. You also need to call `wglGetExtensionsString(HDC)` to get the rest of WGL extensions supported by the card.

Here is a code snippet (you may remove **ARB** suffix) :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/gl.h>

// function ptr: WGL specific extensions for v3.0+
typedef const char* (WINAPI * PFNWGLGETEXTENSIONSSTRINGARBPROC)(HDC hdc);
PFNWGLGETEXTENSIONSSTRINGARBPROC  pwglGetExtensionsStringARB = 0;
#define wglGetExtensionsStringARB pwglGetExtensionsStringARB
...

// get WGL specific extensions for v3.0+
wglGetExtensionsStringARB = (PFNWGLGETEXTENSIONSSTRINGARBPROC)wglGetProcAddress("wglGetExtensionsStringARB");
if(wglGetExtensionsStringARB)
{
    const char* str = wglGetExtensionsStringARB(hdc);
    if(str)
    {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Note that `wglGetExtensionsString()` requires HDC (Handle to Device Context) of the current window display as a parameter. you can get the HDC from the window handle, (HWND);

```
HDC hdc = ::GetDC(hwnd);
```